# HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized with Error Code 0x80070005 with both IIS ans IIS Express

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

After attempting to configure IIS as a replacement for IIS Express, both stopped working and delivered the above error on deploying the .NET Core project in VS2019. According to IIS anonymous authentication is enabled, I also entered explicit user name and password as well as giving my user all rights to work with the project's directory. I restarted the IIS several times and re-created the pools and Pages, as well as repairing VS2019 in hope to get the IIS Express running again at least.
I have no idea what else I could do.

EDIT: I am using IIS10

```
Module
   IIS Web Core
Notification
   AuthenticateRequest
Handler
   aspNetCore
Error Code
   0x80070005
Requested URL
   http://localhost:12345/
Physical Path
   C:\inetpub\...
Logon Method
   Noch unbestimmt
Logon User
   Noch unbestimmt
```

Comment: Are you trying to host a .NET Core application on IIS? I just deployed an API to a VM with IIS and might be able to help you a bit.

Comment: I am, through this one is merely hosting a bot. After all that trouble I think i will stick to IIS Express for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to solve your problem:

1. Right click on the project, go to properties.
2. Select the web, and then you will find a service setting
3. Change the project URL for other port, like http://localhost:44338/.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out myself by now:

For some reason during setting up the IIS and IIS profile (accidentally or by some quirk of VS), the anynomous authentification setting was set to `false`. Which also affected the IIS Express to not work properly anymore. Simply enabled anonymous authentication resolved the issue for both.
`Project Properties` -> `Debug` -> `IIS profile` -> `anonymous authentication: ✓`